# Elasticsearch GET by id return all STORED fields

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, search-engine

I know that for a elastic search search request you can supply a wildcard character '*' to return all Stored fields on matching documents.

Does anyone know if you can provide a similar wildcard for a Get request (get by document id).

The elastic search documentation says you can return certain stored fields by using the Get request in the form

```
curl -XGET http://myserver:9200/myindexname/mydocumenttype/77ca1a6cb2ba2e1adff6bd?fields=xxx
```

This works when I specify specific fields to return, however if I try a wildcard '*' it does not work.  I have also tried to use "_all"

Any ideas?

*Note I am not storing the _source

**Note A work around is to just search with a query to match the _id field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment. Please see elasticsearch [issue 1055](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1055) for more information and updates. If you don't need real-time get the workaround that you proposed (searching by _id) is a reasonable solution for this issue.